# Reading from dev/urandom - system behaviour

Tags: filesystems, devices, random, unix-philosophy

When reading from `dev/urandom`, with say `head` or `dd`, it’s of course expected that the output is always random and different.

How is this handled by UNIX at a low level? Is the file naturally truncated on reading or instead is the file actually an interface for a symmetric cipher or equivalent and as such “reading” is actually the act of executing the cipher.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`/dev/urandom` is a character device, not a regular file. Opening it provides an interface to a driver, usually in the kernel, which handles reads; every time a program reads from `/dev/urandom`, a call is made to the driver, and the driver determines how to provide appropriate content (same as any other character device — `/dev/null`, `/dev/zero`...).

On Linux, this is implemented in [`drivers/char/random.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/char/random.c). It maintains an “entropy pool”, seeded from various sources of random data, and when read, processes the pool data using a ChaCha stream cipher to construct data to return.

Answer (score 8):

`/dev/urandom` is not a 'regular file' (yes, this is the POSIX naming), it is a device. Just like most 'files' on /dev/ So you have plenty of magic behavior there.

- You have `/dev/null`, where no matter how much you write, it never fills
- You have random/urandom/srandom, randomly providing different data each time
- You have `/dev/tty` (and colleagues) where you interact with a terminal
- You have `/dev/full` which always returns "No space left on device" for any write attempy
- You have `/dev/zero` which returns an infinite set of nul bytes

and many more.

These files are actually an interface to interact with a kernel module. So, when you 'read' it, it is actually executing a function which is asked to read as much bytes your program (head, dd, etc.) requested (`/dev/urandom` is a *character* device). This function then handles it internally (based on several entropy pools) in order to fill that buffer (in this case, so that you get pseudorandom contents).