# How is /dev/null implemented?

Tags: linux, io-redirection, io

I don't understand what happens when a process writes to this special file. What happens to all the bytes? And why is writing to /dev/null not cpu-intensive? If you can answer in terms of references to the Linux source code, that would be awesome.

There is this answer on the Arch forums:

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=137861

The buffer is just ignored.

But when I do e.g. cat /dev/urandom > /dev/null, that write_null function must be called several times, or maybe just once and I don't understand how buffers work.

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1676906/what-is-the-practical-mechanic-of-dev-null/1676917#1676917)'s a recent thread with pretty much the same exact question :-)

Comment: Not very verbose but see [null(4)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/null.4.html)

Comment: As for specifically how it's implemented, recall that Linux is, after all, open source.  [This link](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/um/drivers/null.c) is the best I can find quickly, but a more in-depth look can be had from the FreeBSD kernel's `null` device at [https://www.leidinger.net/FreeBSD/dox/dev_null/html/da/dea/null_8c_source.html](https://www.leidinger.net/FreeBSD/dox/dev_null/html/da/dea/null_8c_source.html).  Basically, all that has to happen when writing to `/dev/null` is ... nothing.  The device driver does nothing, and returns a successful result code.

Comment: Yeah I mean `cat /dev/urandom` is pretty cpu intensive in itself so a do nothing process for every line added to it probably wouldn't add much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Linux, `/dev/null` is implemented by a number of functions, including [`write_null`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.7/source/drivers/char/mem.c#L453):

```c
static ssize_t write_null(struct file *file, const char __user *buf,
              size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    return count;
}
```

As you can see, the buffer is completely ignored, and all the function does is return the number of bytes it was asked to write.

This function can be called any number of times, and there is a small cost associated with each call (the cost of calling into the kernel). If you run

```
cat /dev/zero > /dev/null
```

that cost is likely to dominate. `cat` reads from its input (or the files it’s been given) and writes to its output, repeatedly, until either it runs out of things to read, or it fails to write. When reading from `/dev/urandom` however, [the reads are more complex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/606120/86440), and I would expect those to dominate. In both cases, all the “I/O” is CPU-driven, and `cat` will end up using a fair amount of CPU (100% of one logical CPU) — ultimately having the kernel call `write_null` as fast as possible, which proceeds to do nothing as fast as possible.

In more typical circumstances, when `/dev/null` is used to discard a program’s informational output for example, there will be far fewer writes and their overall cost will be negligible compared to whatever else the program is doing.

(Incidentally, you’ll find the implementation of `/dev/zero` just after `/dev/null` in the code linked above.)

Comment: Essentially linux character drivers consist of custom system call implementations passed out to the rest of the kernel in a struct.  As another example /dev/zero's most important feature would be an implementation of read() that zero-filled any buffer passed to it.